# Can't find cause of TypeError: undefined

Tags: javascript, undefined

I am getting the error `TypeError: currentSound is undefined` and `TypeError: track is null` and I can't figure out why, and I would appreciate some help. I've stripped my code down as much as possible to make debugging simpler.

A few clues:

I attempted to use `typeof` (which I'm not very familiar with) to locate where the undefined error was throwing, and it appears to happen inside of the function `playThunder`. I suspect it has to do with the `soundindex` or `potentialThunderSounds.length` sending an extra undefined sound file, but I'm not sure why or how, especially since `(potentialThunderSounds.length - 1)` is subtracting 1 from the `.lenght` to account for 0 as an option in the array.

The `track is null` error throws right away, but the `currentSound` is underfined` error seems to always throw after the second (as the code is now)/last sound has played through.

The error still happens if I only execute the program once by commenting out `masterStart();` so that the code doesn't loop. I thought, originally, that maybe the error was happening if multiple `playThunder()` functions were executed in quick succession, but now I know that can't be the issue.

Thanks!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html
    PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

  <script src="js/howler.core.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

</head>

<body>

  <script>
    (function start() {

      masterStart();

      function masterStart() {
        setTimeout(function() {
          playThunder();
          // masterStart(); // this will loop the code to play sounds continuously. the error happens with or without this
        }, 6000);
      }

      var potentialThunderSounds = [
        getSoundB('audio/58.wav'),
        getSoundB('audio/59.wav')
      ];

      function getSoundB(soundFileName) {
        return new Howl({
          src: [soundFileName],
          autoplay: false,
          loop: false,
          volume: 1,
          fade: 0
        });
      }

      // the error happens in here, I think
      function playThunder() {
        var soundSequence = [];
        for (var x = 0; x < 2; x++) {
          var soundIndex = Math.round(Math.random() * (potentialThunderSounds.length - 1));
          soundSequence.push(potentialThunderSounds[soundIndex]);
        }
        playSoundIfThereIsOne();

        function playSoundIfThereIsOne() {
          var currentSound = soundSequence[0];
          currentSound.play();
          soundSequence.shift();
          currentSound.once('end', playSoundIfThereIsOne);
        }
      }
    }());
  </script>

  <script src="js/howler.core.js"></script>
  <script src="js/siriwave.js"></script>
  <script src="js/player.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It is good practice to not call things before you define them.

Comment: Where am I calling before defining? Do you mean I should place the `getSoundB` and `playThunder` functions above the `playThunder();` call?